# Why no threaded headset cups?

Tags: headset

Threaded bottom brackets

- are much simpler to install
- require minimal tools (press-in requires a $300 press)
- are automatically aligned, as the thread was cut in the factory.

*So what is the reason not to exist headsets, the cups of which thread into the headtube? And be the most often used ones?*

Comment: Note that a lot of high-end mountain bikes are moving to a press-fit bottom bracket. I'm not the right person to tell you why, though :)

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing.  It seems to me to be needless change for change's sake -- a selling point, but actually complicating bike fitting.

Comment: There used to be threaded [headsets](http://sheldonbrown.com/headsets.html).  However I think they have fallen out of fashion.  Perhaps they had a tendency to become loose, which would be catastrophic, as you would no longer be able to steer, or your front fork could disengage.  Compared to your bottom bracket cups coming lose, which would just cause problems with providing power to the bike (cranks would still be connected to the bottom bracket). Also properly designed (not Italian), they are self tightening, and won't ever come loose, for the most part.

Comment: @Kibbee, I think those still use pressed-in cups. No?

Comment: @Kibbee - I've seen threaded headsets loose to the point that the balls were falling out, and they did not catastrophically fail or cause an inability to steer (other than being simply more difficult).  And I cannot imagine how a loose headset could possibly cause a fork to "disengage".  The threadless headsets seem more prone to catastrophic failure.

Comment: There are many tutorials on DIY headset presses, $30 would buy the parts for a luxury version, $10 is achievable.

Comment: @Emyr, if you give an example, I'd upvote it. There seem to be some controversy as to do homemade presses damage the bearing surface of the cups.

Comment: Vorac: two seconds in a search engine gave me http://forums.bicycletutor.com/thread-922.html I've used two bits of wood instead of all those washers and it worked fine.

Comment: @Moz Something like that probably works quite well. Parktool makes a [headset press](http://www.amazon.com/Park-Tool-HHP-3-Mechanic-Bearing/dp/B000VY33TA/) that's remarkably similar to what one could make at home (see reviews), but sells for $70. Their [high end](http://www.amazon.com/Park-Tool-HHP-2-Revised-Hanger/dp/B000R2JJLW) press is $140, not $300, and [similar tools from others](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_125105_-1___202581) can be bought for $70. Which doesn't answer why they aren't threaded, but does give options for installing them that won't break the bank.

Comment: I've used that exact homemade headset press many times and have had no adverse effects. I don't see how it could possibly damage the bearing surface since it doesn't actually touch it. It's basically the same design as the $70 one from Park Tools except with wrenches instead of fancy levers. I've also used the high-end ones and I have to admit, they're much easier to use.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm guessing the move to press-fit BBs is to do with cost (I imagine it's marginally easier/cheaper to manufacture a frame without a threaded BB shell) and carbon fibre (I imagine it's significantly easier/cheaper to manufacture a frame without a threaded metal insert for the BB).

Comment: @OllyHodgson, Trek advertise high-end [bikes](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/mountain/gravity/slash/slash_7/#) for having press-fit BB because "this makes the frame stronger. Ha ha.

Comment: @Vorac You might laugh, but it's actually true! It's not an advantage of press fit as such, more of the bigger bottom bracket shell it uses. They go on to say "This provides a wider stance for the frame’s tubing juncture, resulting in a stronger frame." i.e. the BB shell is wider, giving a larger area on which to weld a bigger down tube. Bigger, stronger, stiffer and potentially lighter.

Comment: @OllyHodgson - Yep, probably cheaper in China, since it's one less manufacturing step on the frame.  Plus of course, the carbon thing.

Comment: @OllyHodgson, then why not 90mm threaded BB (in this price range, threading should be negligibly expensive operation)?

Comment: @Vorac The press-fit BB shell isn't just wider, it's a larger diameter. You need to look at the bigger picture, too: Trek make both aluminium and carbon fibre versions of their frames and would want to standardise components across the range (see my earlier comment about ease of manufacturing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cranks are always spun in the same direction and the threads are located so the cups don't get loose.

The headset does not have a direction where the spinning is happening and it is not possible to have self-tighning cups.

Also fork gives vertical load, directed into the threads. Also there is a big frontal load on the fork which will be transferred into single directional side-load on a thread. A thread can cope with each of these factors separately, but both of these, combined with constant vibrating, will eventually cause the thread to fail, especially in aluminium frame.

Comment: But the torque on a headset cup is vanishingly small, compared to other rotating parts on a bike.  The locknut on top is more than sufficient to prevent loosening if properly installed.  And there's certainly "side-load" on a bottom bracket.  I can see, however, the argument that aluminum bikes have a problem with the threads, and, since we must always driven to use the least common denominator, steel bikes end up with the short end of the stick.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It is only theories I've came up with. I really don't know why the industry gone with the current set up.

Comment: Additionally, threading is _expensive_ to manufacture and involves an extra process step.